# Spring Boot not accepting the given url. Giving 400 instead of 404

Tags: java, spring-boot, jersey, spring-restcontroller

I am trying to map a URL with REST API in Spring Boot.

url: [http://localhost.charlesproxy.com:8080/content/storage/path/someid/x/y/resource/{"reltype":"http://ns.example.com/examplecloud/rel/primary"}/:page](http://localhost.charlesproxy.com:8080/content/storage/path/someid/x/y/resource/%7B%22reltype%22:%22http://ns.example.com/examplecloud/rel/primary%22%7D/:page)

Sending the URL encoded format to Spring Boot:

```
http://localhost.charlesproxy.com:8080/content/storage/path/someid/x/y/resource/%7B%22reltype%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fns.example.com%2Fexamplecloud%2Frel%2Fprimary%22%7D/:page
```

It is giving 400 instead of 404. what's wrong with this URL?

Below is the REST API

```
@GET
@Path("/{path:([^\\:]+/|)}" + ":page")

@ApiParam(required = true) @PathParam("path") String path
```

I tried this request from Postman to localhost and was expecting 404 or hitting my REST API debugger. But getting 400 and not hitting my localhost.

Comment: 400 means invalid request, what makes you think it doesn' thit your URL?

Comment: Those are not Spring mvc controller annotations. Why spring-boot tags?